# RM on an LUKS installation?

Tags: boot, luks, rm, permanent-delete

I am just wondering what will happen if you do `sudo rm -rf / --no-preserve-root` on an LUKS installation... Will the LUKS information be corrupted, rendering it useless (impossible to recover files) or will it skip over it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, effectively you will delete everything on any mounted filesystem. The LUKS container itself will stay intact and you can close and reopen it, but your files will be lost.
One could try to recover the files on the opened LUKS container.